# Replace names of js object properties with abbreviations in JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I want to convert some very large and repetitive javascript objects into JSON strings. Since these objects have a lot of repeating property names, I want some way to replace those property names with abbreviations in the final JSON string using a predefined map of property names to abbreviations. I thought I could use the replacer function provided by JSON.stringify to avoid having to first generate the JSON string and then manipulate it, or manipulate the property names of the original object directly, but I haven't figured out how.

For example, given the following map between property names and abbreviations:

```
var map = {
    prop0: "p0",
    prop1: "p1",
    prop2: "p2"
}
```

I want to be able to convert an object such as the following:

```
var obj = {
    prop0: "value0",
    prop1: [
        {prop2: "value2"},
        {prop2: "value3"},
        {prop2: "value4"}
    ]
}
```

into a JSON string like this:

```
{"p0":"value0","p1":[{"p2":"value2"},{"p2":"value3"},{"p2":"value4"}]}
```

and back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably much better ways to compress JSON, but the [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) and the [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) can be used to modify nested values (sample would not work in IE) :

```js
var obj = { prop0: "value0", prop1: [ { prop2: "value2" }, { prop2: "value3" }, { prop2: "value4" } ] }

var replacer = map => (k, v) => v.constructor !== Object ? v : 
  Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(v).map(([k, v]) => [map[k] || k, v]) )

var json = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer({ prop0: "p0", prop1: "p1", prop2: "p2" }))

var obj2 = JSON.parse(json, replacer({ p0: "prop0", p1: "prop1", p2: "prop2" }))

console.log( json )
console.log( obj2 )
```

Comment: Hmm ok, so if I understand this correctly the replacer function returns a copy of each nested object with its property names replaced? I think I might use this, thanks, although I also may end up compromising on the not editing the original property names condition. Also, I did some tests and in my particular case replacing property names with abbreviations is reducing my JSON string's size by around 40%, so its probably a good first step!

Comment: @Eclogite yes, it creates new object of the values that are object. It can be converted to for loop to be a bit more efficient and to work in IE. You can shorten the keys to single letter or digit to save even more space.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this if there won't be more nested values

```js
var map = {
  prop0: "p0",
  prop1: "p1",
  prop2: "p2"
}

var obj = {
  prop0: "value0",
  prop1: [{
      prop2: "value2"
    },
    {
      prop2: "value3"
    },
    {
      prop2: "value4"
    }
  ]
}
const newObj = {};
for (let key in obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
    newObj[map[key]] = obj[key].map(x => {
      const arrKey = Object.keys(x)[0];
      return {
        [map[arrKey]]: x[arrKey]
      }
    })
  } else {
    newObj[map[key]] = obj[key]
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj))
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use a node module [Json data mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-data-mapper)

It gives you a way to give your own schema and transforms your data into that format.